# Cardinality of a power set (cartesian product)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A = \{0,1,2\}$ and $C = \{1,2\}$

> $|P(A \times C)| = ?$

The answer states $|P(A \times C)| = 2^{3×2} = 2^6 = 64$

What formula/logic is used to obtain this answer please?

Comment: Actually it's obvious what logic is used but i would like to know what theorem is involved so that if a question was changed slightly i wouldn't be stuck

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this sentence; these occasions are exactly what the editing possibility is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two theorems at play here:

**Theorem 1** If $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$ then $|A \times B|= n\cdot m$.

**Theorem 2** If $|C|=n$ then $|\mathcal{P}(C)| = 2^n$.

In your particular example, as $|A|=3$ and $|C|=2$, then by Theorem 1 we have $|A \times C| = 6$. Then, by Theorem 2, we have that $|\mathcal{P}(A \times C)| = 2^6=64.$

Comment: Do you have a citation for **Theorem 2**? All I could find was Cantor’s Theorem, which states that $|C| < |\mathcal{P}(C)|$.